# Problem exporting environment variable in Makefile

Tags: docker, makefile, docker-compose

I would like to export the environment variable in the Makefile. In this case, is to get the IP for debugging with docker

Makefile

```
start:
    export XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=$$(/sbin/ip route|awk '/kernel.*metric/ { print $$9 }') \
    ; docker-compose up -d
```

Update from answers:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  php:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
      environment:
        - XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=docker"
        - XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=${XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST}
```

output:

```
$ make start
export XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=$(/sbin/ip route|awk '/kernel.*metric/ { print $9 }') \
; docker-compose up -d
Starting service_php           ... done

$ docker-compose exec php bash
WARNING: The XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the variable assignment and the `docker` command run in the same shell.  Trivially, put them in the same rule:

```
start:
    XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=$$(/sbin/ip route|awk '/kernel.*metric/ { print $$9 }') \
    docker-compose up -d
```

I took out the `@` because it's probably simply a bad idea, especially if you need to understand what's going on here. You can use `make -s` once your `Makefile` is properly tested if you don't want to see what it's doing.

The purpose of `export` is to expose a variable to subprocesses, but that's not necessary here. Instead, we use the shell's general

```
variable=value anothervar=anothervalue command
```

syntax to set the value of a variable for the duration of a single command.

If the internals of `docker-compose` require the variable to be `export`ed, then of course, you can do that too:

```
start:
    export XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=$$(/sbin/ip route|awk '/kernel.*metric/ { print $$9 }') \
    ; docker-compose up -d
```

Notice how the backslash at the end of the first line of the command list joins the two commands on a single logical line, so they get passed to the same shell instance, and the `;` command separator is required to terminate the first command. (I put the semicolon at beginning of line as an ugly reminder to the reader that this is all one command line.)

Specifically for `docker-compose`, the customary way to set a variable from the command line is with a specific named option;

```
start:
    docker-compose up -e XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=$$(/sbin/ip route|awk '/kernel.*metric/ { print $$9 }') -d
```

There are other ways to solve this such as the GNU Make `.ONESHELL` directive but this is simple and straightforward, and portable to any Make.

Comment: @MadScientist Am I right in saying you could also use the `shell` function, or no?

Comment: You can use a shell function, but (a) it's an anti-pattern to use a shell function in a recipe (after all, you're already _in_ a shell, in a recipe) and (b) John is correct that it won't solve the problem.  In POSIX systems a child process (like a shell you've invoked) can never change the environment of its parent process (like make).  And, each logical line in a recipe is passed to a different shell.  So setting a shell environment variable in one line will be lost when that shell exits.  You can easily try this out with a trivial makefile to see what happens.

Comment: If you don't like escaping `$` in `$(...)` constructs you can always go old-school and use backticks.  But there's no way out of escaping the `$` in `print $9`, regardless of whether you use `$(...)` or `$(shell ...)`.

Comment: I'm still not exporting this variable. When I get in the docker container I still see the warning for the variable that is not set

Comment: Any shell variable is forgotten as soon as the recipe line terminates.   So, if you're expecting it to be set for another recipe line beyond the one shown, it will not be.   If this is the case, you can use a make variable (using the `$(shell ...)`) instead   (assuming the calculation of the variable value is not reliant on other recipes' running).

Comment: If it is, on the other hand, failing in the recipe line shown, then you either missed putting the ` \\ ` (without trailing whitespace) at the end of the first line, or your shell command returned nothing.

Comment: What's in your `docker-compose.yml` file? How exactly does it access the environment?

Comment: Make sure you escaped the `$` as in tripleee's updated version else you indeed will be setting this variable to the empty string.

Comment: If the internals of your `docker-compose` invocation require the variable to be `export`ed for other reasons, you can do that too of course. Updated the answer. I'm guessing that the problem is elsewhere, though.

Comment: I still don't get the environment variable as you see in my update question. Running `make start` and later `docker-compose exec php bash` shows XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST is not set

Comment: That looks like you want it to be set inside the Docker image you are running. That's a Docker question, not a shell question or a Make question.

Comment: @tripleee, I gave tags for docker and docker-compose. Anyway, the variable isn't created in the shell session open so it can't be bound to the docker container and that was the whole point

Comment: Your answer @tripleee was the valid one anyway. For some reason is already in the docker environment, but when I do the `docker-compose exec php bash` shows the that warning. Thanks for this one :)

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the route exists when make is first invoked, you can assign a make variable as opposed to a shell variable as follows:

```
export XDRH_MAKE_VAR:=$(shell /sbin/ip route|awk '/kernel.*metric/ { print $$9 }')

start:
    @echo XDHR_MAKE_VAR=$(XDRH_MAKE_VAR)
    XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=$(XDRH_MAKE_VAR) docker-compose up -d

XDRH_FILE:
    echo $(XDRH_MAKE_VAR) > $@

someother_target:
    XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=$(XDRH_MAKE_VAR) some_other_command
    command_that_uses_it_as_param $(XDRH_MAKE_VAR)

NOTE_does_not_work:
    XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=$(XDRH_MAKE_VAR) echo $$XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST
```

The last one does not work, because the bash shell will expand `$XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST` before assigning it (See [here](https://superuser.com/a/908314/989930)).   Also, the variable is set at make parse time, so if any of your rules effect the route, then this will not be reflected in its value.

If you want to access the value in the shell afterwards, you would want to do something like:

```
bash> make start XDRH_FILE
bash> XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=`cat XDRH_FILE`
bash> docker-compose exec php bash
```

Comment: I've tried this as well and I'm still having the warning after `make start` and later `docker-compose exec php bash` shows XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST is not set

Comment: I'm looking at your updated question.   You should be aware that make does not have the capability of effecting the environment of its calling shell.  So  as soon as make finishes `${XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST}` will resolve to blank  again in the shell...   You can can write the value to a file, and read it again afterwards...   I'll update my answer with this...